# Pandas: Change apply for complex indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code with an `apply`, which accesses another df to get some data and multiply it.

```py
def _apply_values(row):
    if row['symbol'] in df_fiat.index:
        row['usdValue'] = row['tokenBalanceFloat'] * df_fiat.loc[row['symbol'], 'USD']
        row['ethValue'] = row['tokenBalanceFloat'] * df_fiat.loc[row['symbol'], 'ETH']
        row['eurValue'] = row['tokenBalanceFloat'] * df_fiat.loc[row['symbol'], 'EUR']
    else:
        row['usdValue'] = np.NaN
        row['ethValue'] = np.NaN
        row['eurValue'] = np.NaN
    
    return row

df = df.apply(_apply_values, axis='columns')
```

I think this could be done without the `apply` (and thus, maybe more efficient and readable), but I don't know how:

My idea:

1. Assign all the columns to NaN: `df[['usdValue', 'ethValue', 'eurValue']] = np.NaN`
2. Use boolean masking to change only desired rows: `mask = df['symbol'].isin(df_fiat.index)`
3. Now multiply the two things: `df[masked][['usdValue', 'ethValue', 'eurValue']] = df[masked]['tokenBalanceFloat'] * df_fiat.loc[df[masked]['symbol'], [['USD', 'ETH', 'EUR']`

But it doesn't work. How can I translate it to working code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being possible using `df.loc` on the left side of the assignment, and using `reset_index` and `to_numpy()` to ignore the indexes.

```
cols = ['USD', 'ETH', 'EUR']
df[cols] = np.NaN
mask = df['symbol'].isin(df_fiat.index)
df.loc[mask,cols] = df_fiat.loc[df[mask]['symbol'], cols].reset_index(drop=True).mul(df[mask]['tokenBalanceFloat'].reset_index(drop=True), axis=0).to_numpy()

df = df.rename(columns={
    'USD': 'usdValue',
    'ETH': 'ethValue',
    'EUR': 'eurValue'
})
```